# problem with bounded quasi concave function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I have a quasi-concave bounded function $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,1]$. The question is whether $f*f'$ is monotonic, or under which additional conditions one could make such a statement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is denoted by $f*f'$ here?

Comment: By f * f' I mean the product of f and its first derivative (f is a function of a single variable). I am sorry for the ambiguity in the original question. Also it seems clear that this product is not monotonic in general, but which additional conditions would be needed?